# Esc key not working on big sur

Tags: keyboard, big-sur

I have this problem that all of a sudden my ESC key completely stops working, it’s not the actual key because it happens with other keyboards. This happens regularly but on a random basis.

I am running version 11.2.2 (20D80)

Comment: What are you expecting the escape key to do in those instances when it fails?

Comment: I notice that it fails normally when exiting vim or a full window or sometimes Minecraft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an article about this behavior (source: [ESC (Escape) Key not Working on Mac, Fix](https://macreports.com/esc-escape-key-not-working-on-mac-fix/)):

> It appears that this escape key issue is caused by Siri. More specifically, this issue may occur when Siri freezes. To address this, force-quit Siri and ESC will start working again. Here is how:
>
> - On your Mac, open Activity Monitor (Applications > Utilities).
> - Find Siri.
> - Click the Stop (X) button and select Force Quit.

In my case, the issue was that Siri would crash in the background and cause the ESC key to behave as you described. Thus, I went into Activity Monitor to force-quit Siri and the ESC key started working again.

I'm disabling Siri on my Mac from this point on.